# gmail API : Cannot access the list of messages I requested

Tags: json, curl, google-api, gmail-api

So what I'm trying to do is to fetch data from gmail API using unix's shell (curl).

I simply copied this from the json generator to be able to play with the json when I used with curl.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/somebody%40gmail.com/messages?
maxResults=5&includeSpamTrash=false&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then I changed the API_KEY by what I was able to generate in my developer console. However, I cannot get the desired json when I put the link in my browser, or curl it in my shell. How do I generate the right key? Because I already generated from all of the choices in the Credentials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you generate in the Console is the Client ID and Client secret, which are used when you redirect your users to Google. Upon accepting, Google then redirects the user to the url you specify in the console with a code. This code is then finally used to retrieve the `Access Token` which you should use as `{YOUR_API_KEY}`.

Go to [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), and use the Gmail API v1 scopes, and retrieve the access token and use it in your shell.

Comment: Thanks man! This helped me a lot. I got it. Thanks once again!

Comment: No problem Aaron :) Consider accepting the answer so people with similar questions can find it!